# En dash not supported in slim framework 2.6.3

Tags: php, sql-server, slim

I am using PHP slim framework version 2.6.3 to connect to MsSql server version 16 and I have a plan table with below details.

```
CREATE TABLE Plans (
  Id            INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  PlanName      VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO Plans (PlanName) VALUES ('Plan 1');
INSERT INTO Plans (PlanName) VALUES ('Plan – 2');
```

Below is the code which I am using to connect to SQL server.

```
function connect()
    { 
        //Including the constants.php file to get the database constants
        include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Constants.php';
        try { 
             //DB type is 'sqlsrv'
             $this->dsn = DB_TYPE.':Server='.DB_HOST.';Database='.DB_NAME;
             $this->con = new PDO($this->dsn, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

                //finally returning the connection link
                return $this->con;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            // Close the database handler and trigger an error
            self::Close();
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Exception: ".$e;
            //echo json_encode($response);//die;
        }
    }
```

When I try to get all plans I am not getting any data, but I didn't get any error when I try to get first plan.

Also when I replace `en dash` with blank values I get all plans data as well. Is there a way by which I can get all plans without updating plans names and without updating slim framework version ?

**Note:** - Also I can not update Plan names because they are also consumed by different other api's (node, .net). Also I can not change the slim framework version because other teams have their site hosted on same server for same version of PHP.

Code to get all plans.

```
public function getAllPlans() {

        $this->arrReturn['error'] = false;

        $query = "exec [master].[GetAllPlans]";

        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $this->result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (empty($this->result)) {
            $this->arrReturn['message'] = 'No data found!';
            $this->arrReturn['data'] = [];
        } else {
            $this->arrReturn['message'] = 'Found!';
            $this->arrReturn['data'] = $this->result;
        }

        return $this->arrReturn;
    }
```

I am not getting anything in result neither any error.

Comment: _"When I try to get all plans I am not getting any data"_ - Please show us the code that you're having issues with. You're talking about getting the data while you're only showing us the connection.

Comment: Nothing that is UTF8 supports those win-12 something something encoded junk,  (PS I hate those thing, I spent many an hour removing them from various databases over the years)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - I have edited my code question with plans fetching code.

Comment: Thanks @ArtisticPhoenix but I can not update plans names because other api's are also using them and its working fine there.

Comment: Yea they are probably striping them out on their own.  Id ask them.